# OpenID Authencation Flow

Tags: openid

I am studying the OpenID authentication process and I use Google as an example.

From the documentation by Google, there are 9 steps in the process
http://code.google.com/intl/zh-TW/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html#AuthProcess

I am wondering the purpose of Step 3 and Step4. Can it be skipped if I know the login-page address directly? Could anyone explain it to me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could totally do that. As long as you know the endpoint, there's no need to do this discovery. Problem is if they change it, you'll have to rewrite your code in consequence. It's up to you, do you want to code for a long term period, or don't mind to change it if it's needed.

And naturally, what I'm saying only work if they don't change the way you get the endpoint.